# Delete in dataframe python 00:00:00 in EXCEL(.xlsx)

Tags: python, datetime, time, types, type-conversion

I try all different solution from the web but nothing works ! Maybe you have the same problem :

I have a column (DATE) : you can see the picture

[image: ![enter image description here]

I want to delete 00:00:00

Column DATE have : ******** DATE object*********

Answer (score 0):

I put in the code :

## df_second_shift['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_second_shift['DATE'])

## df_second_shift['DATE']=df_second_shift['DATE'].astype(str)

Result :

[image]

For me nothing else works.